# How to not implicitly delete default operators?

Tags: c++, reference, c++17

The code I'm working on spawns multiple threads with each thread doing the same set of well-defined tasks. Those well-defined tasks can be nicely separated into modules which is where I'm failing ATM.

I got a logger class which gets instantiated and initialized

```
class TLogger
{
    int SlotID{};
    States& State;
public:
    void Init(int SlotID, States& State);
    void Log(string Line);
    void LogState();
};
```

The reason is that all loggers write into the same log, henceforth I need the SlotID to write to the log as well. It is immutable as long as that particular thread runs. The state also needs to be logged, but it is mutable. It is mutated by the thread function (which creates & initializes it's own logger).

I'm trying to create a HAL instance which runs in the same thread and accesses hardware. Those accesses need to be logged so I want to give the instance of the HAL running in the current thread a reference to this thread's logger

```
class THAL
{
    nHandle HardwareHandle;
    TLogger& OwnLogger;
public:
    void Init(nHandle HardwareHandle, TLogger& Logger);
};

void THAL::Init(nHandle HardwareHandle, TLogger& Logger)
{
    this->HardwareHandle= HardwareHandle;
    this->OwnLogger = Logger;
}
```

The compiler says

```
'TLogger &TLogger::operator =(const TLogger &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
compiler has generated 'TLogger::operator =' here
'TLogger &TLogger::operator =(const TLogger &)': function was implicitly deleted because 'TLogger' has a data member 'TLogger::State' of reference type (compiling source file THAL.cpp)
see declaration of 'TLogger::State' (compiling source file THAL.cpp)
```

If I read this right, the compiler does ALMOST the right thing by giving my class gets an =-operator, but kills it afterwards.

Save for switching to raw pointers, how can I get a reference to the thread-local logger into the thread-local HAL?

If I only had one thread, I'd declare everything as static singletons and call it a day but alas, this isn't a hobby project with optional boundary conditions.

Comment: default `operator=` cannot be really generated with `const members` or `reference members`.

Comment: You should either use a smart pointer or a [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) to make your class copiable.

Comment: 1) Why those `init` methods, instead of a constructor? 2) Why having `operator=` is a requirement for you? I, as far as the code is written, see no need for it (if you switch those `init` functions to constructors, that is).

Comment: types holding a reference are a bit "special" and of limited use. Btw your last paragraph made me smile. It is hobby projects where I can get along without singletons, but unfortunately not at work ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, your current code has another problem apart from the one mentioned in the question. `TLogger` too can't have a default constructor since non-static reference members can't be initialized with default constructors. One way I see to get around this is moving `Init()` functionality to the constructors (which are supposed to *initialize* objects before usage) of the classes and using a member-initializer list as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

class States{
    const static size_t SIZE = 1<<20;
    int a[SIZE];
    int dataLoad_ = 0;
    public:
    void setData(int x);
};

void States::setData(int x) {
    if(dataLoad_ < SIZE - 1) {
        a[dataLoad_++] = x;
    }
}

class TLogger
{
    size_t SlotID_ {};
    States& State_;
public:
    TLogger(int SlotID, States& State);
    void Log(std::string Line);
    void LogState();
};

TLogger::TLogger(int SlotID, States& State):
SlotID_(SlotID),State_(State)
{}

void TLogger::Log(std::string Line) {
    std::cout<<"[slot "<<SlotID_<<"] :"<<Line<<'\n';
}

class THAL
{
    using nHandle = int;
    nHandle HardwareHandle_;
    TLogger& Logger_;
public:
    THAL(nHandle HardwareHandle, TLogger& Logger);
    ~THAL();
};

THAL::THAL(nHandle HardwareHandle, TLogger& Logger):
HardwareHandle_(HardwareHandle),
Logger_(Logger)
{}

THAL::~THAL() {
    Logger_.Log("Closing device " + std::to_string(HardwareHandle_));
}

void runThread(States* state, int x) {
    // int slotId(std::hash<std::thread::id>(std::this_thread::get_id()));
    int slotId = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());
    TLogger logger(slotId, *state);
    THAL hw(1, logger);
}

int main() {
    States* state = new States;
    state->setData(5);
    std::thread t(runThread, state, 1);
    std::thread t2(runThread, state, 2);
    t.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Possible output:

```
[slot 18446744072947625951] :Closing device 2
[slot 18446744071970489560] :Closing device 1
```

Comment: Tried, didn't work. This code isn't an island but runs within a template. Once I tried to transfer all the guts of it into a wholly new project, hardware access ceased working. But within this code template, I get an object to work in. The SlotID gets transferred into that object some time later (because reasons). When I tried to initialize everything in constructors (and made it compile), the SlotID was always some garbage value. I only got a few weeks left and whole crap of app-level stuff to write, so rewriting everything in a non-WTF way from scratch ain't an option. Maybe next year...

Comment: @ReBoot From OP, is there any purpose for the TLogger object to exist between `TLogger()` and `init()`? If not then could `Tlogger` instance's creation be deferred to the _later point_ when `SlotId` is available?

Comment: When I declare a TLogger Logger; member in the thread class head, the compiler either complains about an unitialized member or calls the default constructor when I initialize with {}. While I could suppress the warning about an unitialized member, doing so feels less-than-clean. Additionally, I already experienced bugs, sometimes subtile, sometimes not, creeping in due to uninitialized variables. Is there a way to make ABSOLUTELY SURE nothing uninitialized gets accessed, like, ever (let's say after refactoring while not thinking of that particular problem)?

Comment: @ReBoot Which uninitialized members are being referred to here? Is it either of `States` or `SlotID`?

Comment: TLogger & THAL become uninitialized members in the overarching thread class unless I initialize them with ANY constructor which brings the aftermentioned problem of initializing constructors not working because the SlotID is unknown while creating the overarching class. But you just made me think of something! I could switch to initializing constructors passing SlotID as reference (so having SlotID& as members of Logger/HAL) so when it gets set by the framework later, I still get it right. Imma try that ASAP.